# Save URL to file and interrogate it then end result is different between querying the URL or the file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to save a URL to a file then retrieving it:

This is working:

```
#$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date" -Method Get

$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date#version-history" -Method Get

# Cast current version to a version

$build = [Version]"16.0.16731.20600"

# Get the version using regex

$content -match "<a href=`"(?<Channel>.+?)`".+?>Version (?<Version>\d{4}) \(Build $($build.Build)\.$($build.Revision)\)"

# Output the data

$output = [PSCustomObject]@{

Build = $build

Version = $Matches['Version']

Channel = ($Matches['Channel'] -split "#")[0]

}

Write-Output $output
```

The end result is:

Build Version Channel

---

16.0.16731.20600 2308 semi-annual-enterprise-channel

Then saving the URL to a file. In my brower the file is looking good.

```
$content | out-file \\server\version.html

Testing the file in my browser and it is looking good.

# Get version information

$content=get-content \\server\version.html

# Cast current version to a version

$build = [Version]"16.0.16731.20600"

# Get the version using regex

$content -match "<a href=`"(?<Channel>.+?)`".+?>Version (?<Version>\d{4}) \(Build $($build.Build)\.$($build.Revision)\)"

# Output the data

$output = [PSCustomObject]@{

Build = $build

Version = $Matches['Version']

Channel = ($Matches['Channel'] -split "#")[0]

}

Write-Output $output
```

The the end result is

Write-Output $output

Version 2308 (Build 16731.20600)
ative-path">Version 2302 (Build 16130.20928)

Indexation impossible dans un tableau Null.

Au caractère Ligne:12 : 1

- $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
- 
- CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Another way might be to parse the Webpage then saving the result. I found this:

```
$content=get-content \\server\Sources\version.html
# Cast current version to a version
$results = switch -Regex ($Content){
    '>(.+?)/.+?\s+(.+?)\s{2,}' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Version   = $Matches.1
            Date = $matches.2 -as [datetime]
        }
    }
}

$results | Sort-Object -Property date -Descending
```

But it is not returning all the value or the correct values.

Thanks,